# Read/Write Double byte chars from java application hosted on WAS8.5.5

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, websphere

Currently our application hosted on the WAS6.1, complied with Java 1.5. This application able to read/write double byte (Japanese) chars from/to database(Sql Server 2008). I recompiled the same code using Java 1.7 and deployed on WAS8.5.5 Server. But from the WAS8.5.5 hosted application, whenever I read the double byte chars and storing on the db, those chars are stored as ???. I guess WAS8.5.5 application not able to process these chars as UTF-8. Is there any setting on the JVM to be changed to read all the .class files as UTF-8? Both the servers has the same code. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue.. But updating this thread, thinking this may helps someone. 
Issue was with the JDBC driver. The way SQL Server driver working in WAS 6.1.1 not working in the same way in WAS 8.5.5. When I created a new datasource in WAS 8.5.5, I am getting some default custom properties. One of the custom property "sendStringParametersAsUnicode" value set as false. Where as the expected value is true. Once I changed to true, I am able to write double byte chars to database properly.

Answer (score 1):

Java strings are UTF-16 encoded internally, so when you read a string from a DB is the JDBC driver responsible for deserializing any DB internal format to a java String.

There is no way to set the compiler to prevent this. Moreover while .java sources can be encoded in different ways, the same is not true to bytecode inside class files.

I would instead investigate either the JDBC driver (less probable) or HTTP transport.

If you want to make a test try reading a value from DB and writing it again on DB without passing through request / response serialization / deserialization, if it stays true then you found the culprit.

Most of the time the problem comes from either interpreting the incoming stream or writing the outgoing one with a wrong default.

Check [IBM KB](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/trun_svr_utf.html) for more information.

#### EDIT

I verified your example, and to my great surprise changing the source encoding did change the resulting output.

So i tried it calling it from cmd line setting the console to utf-8 (`chcp 65001`) and after a few check I discovered what was amiss, when you change the encoding of the java source , Eclipse changes the default encoding when running the application.

I double checked class file by doing an md5sum of the compiled class.

So certainly what you get on the console is the consequence of the file.encoding property used when running your test application.

I still believe you should check encoding of request input and result output because they strongly depend on the container and changing version of websphere can have resulted in different defaults in some configurations, also just changing instance of the container will also reset configuration done (that must be re-applied).

Comment: I wrote a simple class which reads the double byte chars from the db and prints the same on the Console. I saved this class, as my OS is Windows, by default the class saved in cp1252 encoding format. When I ran this class, the double byte chars are printed as ???. When I saved the same class in UTF-8 encoding and ran, the double byte chars printed properly. I am not expecting the issue is with the Driver and  request / response serialization / deserialization.

Comment: When you say class,  are you meaning .java source file?

Comment: Yes.. I meant .java source file.

Comment: There is something I'm missing here, I can't see the connection between source file encoding and string encoding returned from a DB. How do you get this fields ? I think you should post your simple class. By the way, how do you set the source file encoding?

Comment: I added the sample class and it's output. I am not sure the .java file encoding format is the issue or not, but from my test I felt it.

Comment: Java strings are UTF-*16* encoded internally, i.e. as `chars`.